# Python Dictionary contains List as Value - How to update?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has value as a list.

```
dictionary = { 
               'C1' : [10,20,30] 
               'C2' : [20,30,40]
             }
```

Let's say I want to increment all the values in list of C1 by 10, how do I do it?

`dictionary.get('C1')` gives me the list but how do i update it?

Comment: Woosh! That was quick. thanks a lot! I'm a newbie to Python, so probably this was too silly a question to ask. All answers have taught me something. Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
>>> dictionary = {'C1' : [10,20,30],'C2' : [20,30,40]}
>>> dictionary['C1'] = [x+1 for x in dictionary['C1']]
>>> dictionary
{'C2': [20, 30, 40], 'C1': [11, 21, 31]}
```

Comment: Why is C2 printed before C1?

Comment: From Python version 3.7, dictionaries are ordered. In Python 3.6 and earlier, dictionaries are unordered.

Answer (score 5):

An accessed dictionary value (a list in this case) is the original value, separate from the dictionary which is used to access it. You would increment the values in the list the same way whether it's in a dictionary or not:

```
l = dictionary.get('C1')
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] += 10
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dictionary["C1"]=map(lambda x:x+10,dictionary["C1"])
```

Should do it...

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this:

```
original_list = dictionary.get('C1')
new_list = []
for item in original_list:
  new_list.append(item+10)
dictionary['C1'] = new_list
```

Comment: Why `dictionary.get`? Because it returns a `None` and doesn't raise an exception? You just unnecessarily delay the exception, and a non-existent key is different than an existent one that has `None` for a value.

Answer (score 1):

why not just skip .get altogether and do something like this?:

```
for x in range(len(dictionary["C1"]))
    dictionary["C1"][x] += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,j in dictionary .items():
    if i=='C1':
        c=[]
        for k in j:
            j=k+10
            c.append(j)
            dictionary .update({i:c})
```