# Python Dictionary contains List as Value - How to update based on some other input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary where the value is a 2 item list. The first item is a count of how many times I have seen the key. The 2nd item is another integer which I need to update based on some input.

```
dictionary = { 
               'key1' : [1, 200] 
               'key2' : [1, 100]
             }
```

Suppose, I encounter `key1` again and the input is `150`. So the update operation should yield

```
dictionary = { 
                   'key1' : [2, 350] 
                   'key2' : [1, 100]
                 }
```

How do I do it? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527454/python-dictionary-contains-list-as-value-how-to-update) but doesn't help. Please suggest. I am using Python 3.

EDIT:

Before posting this, I tried below:

```
data = defaultdict(list)
key = requestTokens[1] # one of the input that works as a key
data[key][0] +=1
data[key][1] += int(statusTokens[1]) #another input is statusTokens[1] a string
```

But I am getting error

```
data[key][0] +=1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Do you know how dictionaries work? If not, you should have a look at the docs. You can modify lists and dicts in-place...

Comment: What's the problem? All you need to do is to add some numbers.

Comment: @Aran-Fey see the EDIT

Comment: @ForceBru see the EDIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> di = {'key1': [1,200], 'key2':[1,100]}
>>> di
{'key1': [1, 200], 'key2': [1, 100]}
>>> di['key1'][0] += 1
>>> di['key1'][1] += 150
>>> di
{'key1': [1, 300], 'key2': [1, 100]}
>>>
```

So looking at the above example you can see that it is first accessing the key then the index in the array and setting it to a new value. 
`di['key1'][0] += 1` is incrementing it by 1 
`di['key1'][1] += 150` is adding the new value

Comment: I followed this approach before posting the question but getting "list index out of range" error. Please see the updated post

Comment: Are you arrays initialized?  Is the value of `key = requestTokens[1]` key what you expect?